# String extract, to extract number from a text

Tags: r, regex, stringr

How can I extract a 3 digit number from text which is not a date?

Example:

```
"she is born on 02-05-1934 and she is 200 years old."
```

So, how do i extract 200 from here

I was using the code:

```
str_extract(data,"[[:digit:]]{3}")
```

but it's returning the output of `-193`.

Comment: Try `str_extract(str1, "(?<=\\s)\\d+(?=\\s)")`

Comment: adding spaces in your pattern should work too. `as.numeric(str_extract(data,"\\s[[:digit:]]{3}\\s"))`

Answer (score 5):

We can use regexlookarounds to specify the digits are preceded by space and followed by space (based on the pattern showed)

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(str_extract(str1, "(?<=\\s)\\d+(?=\\s)"))
#[1] 200
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "she is born on 02-05-1934 and she is 200 years old"
```